# Websphere 8.x Fails to publish in Eclipse Juno thanks to null pointer

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I am trying to start my WAS 8.x server using eclipse. It used to work just fine, however, all of the sudden it has been failing to publish with a popup box (in Eclipse) that says..

> 'Publishing to Websphere Application Server v8.5 at localhost...' has encountered a problem.
>
> Could not publish to the server.

```
Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have removed all applications and I still get this error. It appears to be a "bad error" because the server seems to be running properly. Here is the error log from Eclipse...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.ws.ast.st.core.internal.GenericModuleSupportExtensionHelper.getModuleSupportClasses(GenericModuleSupportExtensionHelper.java:222)
at com.ibm.ws.ast.st.v85.core.internal.WASServerBehaviour.publishGenericModules(WASServerBehaviour.java:2084)
at com.ibm.ws.ast.st.v85.core.internal.WASServerBehaviour.publishModules(WASServerBehaviour.java:1990)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:955)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3108)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You can see the Eclipse log view using `Window / Show View / Error Log`. Or look in the workspace `.metadata` directory for the `.log` file.